# Как реализовать передачу значения по маркеру в webview связанным с listview?

Tags: listview, google-maps, webview, marker

Хочу реализовать нажатие по названию маркера и перейти на html документ который открывается в webview.

MapsActivity:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private WebView mwebview;

private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

private GoogleMap mMap;


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if( mGoogleApiClient != null )
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder( this )
            .enableAutoManage( this, 0, this )
            .addApi( Places.GEO_DATA_API )
            .addApi( Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
            .build();
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    enableMyLocation();

    LatLng piligrim = new LatLng(55.92576, 37.23328);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(piligrim).title("Piligrim Porto"));
    LatLng nikola = new LatLng(54.75016, 35.60069);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(nikola).title("Никола-Ленивец"));
    LatLng abramcevo = new LatLng(56.23367, 37.96789);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(abramcevo).title("Усадьба Абрамцево"));
    LatLng muzei = new LatLng(55.19015, 40.16336);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(muzei).title("Музей деревянного зодчества \"Лесная Крепость\""));
    LatLng vodopad = new LatLng(56.26853, 38.34439);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vodopad).title("Водопад Гремячий"));
    LatLng vodopad2 = new LatLng(55.26853, 35.34439);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vodopad2).title("Водопад Радужный"));
    LatLng etnomir = new LatLng(55.24281, 36.42808);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(etnomir).title("Этномир"));
    LatLng zapovednik = new LatLng(54.91070, 37.57107);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(zapovednik).title("Приокско-террасный заповедник"));
    LatLng kremel = new LatLng(55.10321, 38.75233);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(kremel).title("Коломенский кремль"));
    LatLng kremel2 = new LatLng(56.03777, 35.95708);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(kremel2).title("Волоколамский кремль"));
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
            intent.putExtra("intent1", 1);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
// TODO: Please implement GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener to

private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
    } else if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}




@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Моё местоположение", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Данное местоположение:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }

    if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        enableMyLocation();
    } else {
        mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    if (mPermissionDenied) {
        showMissingPermissionError();
        mPermissionDenied = false;
    }
}


private void showMissingPermissionError() {
    PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
            .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Класс webview (Place1):

```
private WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place1);
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String resName ="n" + intent1.getIntExtra("title", 0);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + resName + ".html");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему вот так, если кому то понадобится на будущее:

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            String title = marker.getTitle();
            if ("Piligrim Porto".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Никола-Ленивец".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", 1);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Усадьба Абрамцево".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", 2);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Музей деревянного зодчества \"Лесная Крепость\"".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", 3);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Водопад Гремячий".equals(title)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                    intent.putExtra("title", 4);
                    startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Водопад Радужный".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 5);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Этномир".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 6);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Приокско-террасный заповедник".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 7);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Коломенский кремль".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 8);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if ("Волоколамский кремль".equals(title)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 9);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Place1.class);;
                intent.putExtra("title", 4);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```